# How do I tell Google Reader to mark the currently-shown page as read if I know it's in one of my subscribed feeds?

Tags: google-reader, bookmarklet

Occasionally, I browse to (i.e., arrive at without using Google Reader) a URL that I know is an item in one of my subscribed feeds. (One common way this happens is through Twitter.) I'm wondering if there's a way to tell Google Reader not to keep that page read anymore. It doesn't matter whether it remotely marks the item as read or opens Google Reader to that item (each has its advantages).

I thought the `Next »` bookmarklet provided by Google Reader did part of what I wanted, but I've since found that it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. Google Reader uses RSS feeds (and sometimes ATOM feeds) to grab content. RSS feeds are, for the most part, grabbing data from the blog/site's database and outputting it in a format for feed readers. They have no interaction with the actual site itself (unless that site is setup in a funky manner).

Even using the next bookmarklet, it still wouldn't work, because of how the whole system is setup.

Until a complete api for reader is released, and somebody makes a custom version with a plugin for your browser, you're out of luck on that front.

Comment: You're right that the `Next »` bookmarklet doesn't mark the current page read. However, I don't see why the content being delivered through RSS feeds would prevent that from working. The RSS feeds carry information about the source URL, otherwise clicking the RSS item's title wouldn't be able to take you to the web page.

Comment: RSS is not a part of the database. RSS is one file, where the database is lots of tables.

Think of it this way:
  I have an excel sheet with all of the data for my posts in it's own cell. I create a new word document that uses the excel data, but just grabs the data and arranges it in a specific way. You have a second excel sheet that is all the items placed in your reader account. This sheet grabs the word document and splits it apart. The reader sheet doesn't even know that the site's sheet exists, because it might not (there are lots of ways to set up rss). You simply can't do it.